# Flutter TextField input to not disappear after save/done

Tags: flutter, textfield

how can i make the user input to stay and not disappear after users done so next time the user want to update the text they get to clear the text fileds manually!

```
Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'option',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (input) => _alOne2 = input,
                ),
              )
```

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by changing TextField to TextFormField and using its initial value .i am using several fields in the same page and in that case had to create a Controller for each field.